# From which expansion is this magic the gathering card?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

From which expansion is this magic the gathering card?

[image]

Comment: @doppelgreener, that most excellent post applies to English Cards.  It is not clear if it applies to non-English cards or not.

Comment: According to the chart in the answer to the question to which this question was found to be a duplicate, this card is from 4th edition (white border, with a Copyright of 1995, and no set symbol)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's Meekstone

First printed in Alpha, but this particular one is probably from fourth Edition due to the look and wording on the card.

http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=2058